# How do I debug Alsa configuration file errors?

Tags: alsa

I've got an embedded device with ALSA support, and I'm trying to figure out how to get dsnoop working. The reason is that I want two applications to share the microphone input. But the problem is that ALSA seems to ignore `/etc/asound.conf` entirely. E.g. `arecord --list-pcms` does not list the pcm's defined there. How can I check the results of `/etc/asound.conf` parsing?

There is a mysterious line in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`, "errors false". Does this do anything?

Comment: What operating system does the device have on it? There may be some files of interest under `/usr/share/alsa/pcm/`, including a `dsnoop.conf` file.

Comment: Linux 2.6.35, MIPS(SMP). There is indeed a `dsnoop.conf` file, which has a `pcm.!dsnoop` entry. It's parameterized, taking 5 args (card dev subdev format rate)

Comment: New device, completely different vendor, still the same ALSA problems :( It's really not impressive when in 2015 Linux still can't share audio input.

Comment: Have you tried creating `~/.asoundrc` with your custom definitions? Or even copying `/etc/asound.conf` or `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` to `~/.asoundrc`? It is always advisable to do this rather than messing around with `/etc/asound.conf` or `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

To enable `dsnoop` by default, your particular device needs a file with the proper settings in `/usr/share/alsa/cards/`.

To check whether dsnoop works at all, try `arecord -D dsnoop -f dat test.wav`.

The `errors false` parameter of the `load`* functions is not related to your problem; it specifies that not error should be raised when one of those files is not found.

Comment: `alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm_dsnoop.c:615:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave`. I can't find any file obviously related to my device in `/usr/share/alsa/cards/`.

Comment: Does `arecord -D plughw -f dat test.wav` work?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Basic sound functionality works, even within the two apps I have. They just can't run concurrently.

Comment: Does your hardware driver support `mmap`?

Comment: `arecord -D plughw -f dat --mmap test.wav` works too, so I think mmap is supported.

Comment: For that, you'd have to test with `hw` instead of `plughw`.

Comment: `arecord -D hw -f dat --mmap test.wav` works too. But let's take one step back: If `dsnoop` fails because of a lack of `mmap`, where could I have discovered that?

Comment: Is "`unable to open slave`" the only error message from `arecord`?

Comment: No, there´s also `pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params` and `main:654: audio open error: Invalid argument`. (before and after "unable to open slave").

Comment: So your sound driver (whatever it is) does not support the default parameters of the `dsnoop` plugin.